# python fabric set ssh_path via config yaml file

Tags: python, python-3.x, fabric

What is the proper way to store and use a custom ssh path for fabric to run

This does not seem to be working:

fabric.yaml:

```
set_runtime_ssh_path: 'my/ssh/path'
```

main.py:

```
with open('fabric.yaml') as config_file:
config = yaml.safe_load(config_file)
with Connection('example.com',
                connect_kwargs={'set_runtime_ssh_path': config.get('set_runtime_ssh_path'), 'password': 'password'}) as conn:
    conn.run('whoami', pty=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
config = Config(runtime_ssh_path = "path/to/ssh")
```

Keep in mind that you can not change the executable flask used, this is just to load any config files (like .ssh/config)